# How do I retrieve & print ip2long IP from db?

Tags: php, printing, ip, echo

third question today sorry.

I figured out how to insert IP addresses into sql (woohoo), it's worked.

```
if (empty($userid)) {
    $names= array('Goat', 'Goat Toucher', 'Goat Fondler', 'Goat Farmer', 'Goat Keeper', 'Goat Herder', 'Goat Stalker', 'Goat Lover', 'Ettamogah', 'Bungle Bungle', 'Teapot', 'Fuzzyface', 'Walker', 'Stroker', 'Eggtrump', 'Ghoul', 'Who', 'of Doom', 'of Mercy', 'of JFC', 'From Above', 'Strangler', 'Pooper', 'Servant', 'Bunny', 'Layer', 'Slayer', 'Hu Wong', 'Phu King Phat', 'Entombed', 'Orama', 'Wobbly Finger', 'Crooked Toe', 'Up the Duff', 'Lover', 'Geek', 'Freak', 'Jelly Bottom', 'Invader', 'Impaler', 'Arouser', 'Handler', 'Googly Eyes', 'Buddha Belly', 'Big Nose', 'No Nose', 'Ogre', 'Pink', 'Princess', 'Angel', 'Devil', 'Demon', 'Thunder Thighs', 'Sugar Lips', 'Cupcake', 'Sweetiechops', 'Midget', 'Loony', 'Anonymous');
            $random = rand(0,count($names)-1);
            $name= $names[$random];
    $ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $ip = ip2long($ip);
    $sql = ("insert into cometchat_guests (name,lastactivity,ip) values ('Guest    ".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."','".getTimeStamp()."','".$ip."')");
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $userid = mysql_insert_id();
    setcookie($cookiePrefix.'guest', base64_encode($userid), time()+3600*24*365, "/");
}

return $userid;
```

Now.. I need to print it.

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) FROM 'user' WHERE 1
```

What do I put after that?

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) FROM 'user' WHERE 1 = $uid or

SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) FROM 'user' WHERE 1 echo $ip
```

what? PHP gives me a headache haha, but I'm having fun learning!

Here's where I need to print it:

```
if($owner == 1 || in_array($userid,$moderatorUserIDs))
        SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) FROM 'cometchat_guests' WHERE 1 {
    $options="<input type=button value='".$chatrooms_language[40]."'     onClick=javascript:".$caller."kickUser($uid,0);$close class='invitebutton'>
    <input type=button value='".$chatrooms_language[41]."'     onClick=javascript:".$caller."banUser($uid,0);$close class='invitebutton'>".$options;
}
```

OK so I think I got it

__

```
if($owner == 1 || in_array($userid,$moderatorUserIDs)) {

    $options="<input type=button value='".$chatrooms_language[40]."'     onClick=javascript:".$caller."kickUser($uid,0);$close class='invitebutton'>
    <input type=button value='".$chatrooms_language[41]."'     onClick=javascript:".$caller."banUser($uid,0);$close class='invitebutton'>".$options;
$sql = getGuestDetails($uid);
$sql = "SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) FROM 'cometchat_guests' WHERE 'userid' = 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Tried it.. it doesn't work. There's nothing there it's just blank. I'm going to scream! I'm quickly starting to hate PHP. Why won't it JUST PRINT OMG

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: +1 for @NullPointer. true start adopting new one

Comment: You'd better take a good book and learn. ;)

Comment: It's not me using it, that's the code CometChat comes with..

Comment: I just wanna know what goes after WHERE 1.. is WHERE 1 = $uid.. or is it WHERE 1($uid) ?

Comment: why are you not fetching  result ?